# Como subir arquivo via ajax com Rails 4?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arquivo

Quero transferir um arquivo pdf para processar no meu controlador e depois retorná-lo, enquanto ele fica sendo processado no *backend*, gostaria que aparece uma barra ou círculo de carregando. Entretanto, estou tendo problemas em como enviar o arquivo assincronamente. Como eu faço para enviar um arquivo assíncrono através do Rails 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.sitepoint.com/asynchronous-file-uploads-rails/

https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart

https://medium.com/rails-ember-beyond/ajax-file-upload-in-rails-using-dropzone-and-carrierwave-6f5436fdfdb0#.4paxrz751

Existe várias soluções para fazer isso. Hoje eu utilizo a solução a CarrierWave + DropDzone

---

Felipe,
O método do POST/PUT do HTTP permite você fazer uma conexão client & server de arquivos binários.

Para que você consiga fazer o seu controlador aceitar esse tipo de arquivo você terá que preparar um MODEL faça a captura deste arquivo para o transforme no arquivo desejado "PDF, JPG,PNG....

### model/asset.rb

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assetable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

lembra de olhar como configurar o carrierwave

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

### model/nfes.rb

```
has_one :asset, :class_name => "Asset", as: :assetable, dependent: :destroy
```

### NfesController.rb

```
respond_to :html, :xml, :json, :js
...
private
def nfe_params
  params.require(:nfe).permit(:build_id, :due_at, asset_attributes:[:id, :file])
end
```

### views/new.html.slim

```
form_for @nfe, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone"}, method: :post do |f| 
  div.fallback
  - f.object.build_asset if f.object.asset.blank? 
  = f.fields_for :asset  do |asset|
  = asset.file_field :file
  = f.submit "Upload"
```

Comment: Minha dúvida é como ele faz pra subir o arquivo e quando eu clico no `submit`, ele mudar o conteúdo da página, você poderia dar um exemplo aqui?

Comment: @Breno Perucchi evite postar apenas links como respostas, coloque as partes relevantes na sua resposta.

Comment: @magicHat A pergunta foi muito genérica. Não envolvia, como resolver isto ou estou com problema nisso e sim gostaria de uma solução para isso. Não sabia que links não eram apropriados para respostas.

Comment: Eu penso quando for assim melhor colocar no comentário... Sei lá...Mas o fato de colocar os links, é pq se sai do ar, ai fica quebrado,,,

Comment: @MagicHat postei algo consistente

Comment: Olha que diferença...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar funcionou?